# Removing duplicates with aggregated values that cancel out

Tags: duplicates, ssms

I am attempting to remove duplicates that are found in the serial number, but only if the amount bill of the duplicate serial number cancels out when aggregating the amount bill.  For example, there are five serial number as "abc-321", but have five different amount dues ($500, $250, $-250, $30, $-30).  The four duplicates would be $250, $-250, $30, $-30, because adding them together would cancel them or be 0.
I was only able to come up with a query to identify what the duplicate serial numbers are, but not sure how to aggregate them to cancel them out.

```
SELECT a.Serial, a.BillAmt, a.Date, a.Code 
FROM TableA a 
WHERE (a.Serial) in 
               (SELECT Serial 
                FROM TableA a 
                GROUP BY Serial 
                HAVING COUNT(Serial)>1) 
GROUP BY a.Serial, a.BillAmt, a.Date, a.Code 
ORDER BY a.Serial ASC;
```

Sample Output:

```
+--------+---------+----------+------+
|Serial  | BillAmt | Date     | Code |
+--------+---------+----------+------+
|abc-112 | $240    | 20200720 | MPO  |
|abc-112 | -$400   | 20200527 | CPP  |
|acc-130 | $300    | 20200515 | CPP  |
|acc-130 | $300    | 20200420 | DUB  |
|acc-130 | -$300   | 20200515 | CPP  |
|bcc-111 | $500    | 20200701 | MPO  |
|bcc-111 | -$500   | 20200701 | MPO  |
|caa-321 | $700    | 20200805 | DUB  |
|caa-321 | $700    | 20200805 | MPO  |
+--------+---------+----------+------+
```

Desire Results:

```
+--------+---------+----------+------+
|Serial  | BillAmt | Date     | Code |
+--------+---------+----------+------+
|abc-112 | $240    | 20200720 | MPO  |
|abc-112 | -$400   | 20200527 | CPP  |
|acc-130 | $300    | 20200420 | DUB  |
|caa-321 | $700    | 20200805 | DUB  |
|caa-321 | $700    | 20200805 | MPO  |
+--------+---------+----------+------+
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  What if there are more than two rows with the same absolute value?

Comment: Please only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using.

Comment: Tip: Don't reuse the same table alias. Can be very confusing.

Comment: what if there are $500, $250, $-250,$250, $30, $-30, $-30

Comment: Thank you all for the response and my apologies for how I posted my question.  This is my first question posted on this site.

Comment: @Larnu - The only reason why I didn't post the actual RDBMS or actual data is because my company values the privacy of their data and so I tried to substitute the data and the columns that were being used.

Comment: @jarlh - Noted on not using the same alias tables moving forward.  Thank you.

Comment: @LONG 22 - Thank you for posting that question.  Yes, my apologies.  I didn't include all the checking criteria.  Based on your example, the code has to match as well as the date.  So the $-30 would have either different date or different code and both would have to match up along with the bill amount to cancel out.

Comment: You tagged 2 conflicting RDBMS because your company values privacy? That doesn't make any sense @plummdg . As for the data, I said "sample" not actual. We would *never* ask you to supply real world data.

Comment: @Larnu - Sorry about that.  I misunderstood what you were asking.  I apply the correction as well as providing a sample output and the desire results.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare the data to itself.  You can do this by using a JOIN statement from TableA to TableA.

Here's what worked for me, with some test data.  I did it by doing a partial OUTER JOIN (specifically a LEFT JOIN), with one of the JOIN conditions being the BillAmt's cancelling.  Then in the WHERE, I look for where the JOIN failed.  This is will be where the RIGHT side is NULL.

```
CREATE TABLE TableA (
Serial VARCHAR(10),
BillAmt DOUBLE,
`Date` DATE,
Code INT
);

INSERT INTO TableA (Serial, BillAmt, Date, Code) VALUES
('abc-321',500,'2021-06-01',1),
('abc-321',250,'2021-06-02',1),
('abc-321',-250,'2021-06-03',1),
('abc-321',50,'2021-06-04',1),
('abc-321',-50,'2021-06-05',1),
('abc-321',123,'2021-06-06',1);

SELECT a.Serial, a.BillAmt, a.Date, a.Code 
FROM TableA AS a
LEFT JOIN TableA AS b
  ON a.Serial = b.Serial
 AND a.BillAmt = (b.BillAmt * -1)
WHERE b.Serial IS NULL;
```

It gives this output:

```
+---------+---------+------------+------+
| Serial  | BillAmt | Date       | Code |
+---------+---------+------------+------+
| abc-321 |     500 | 2021-06-01 |    1 |
| abc-321 |     123 | 2021-06-06 |    1 |
+---------+---------+------------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: $250, $-250, $-250 ?

Comment: @Serg - Ugh. Yea, probably a problem. TBH, they probably need stronger matching between A and B than just the prices match.  There should be a Transaction ID or Expense ID or something.

Comment: Yes.  My apologies.  I didn't include all the criteria, only that the bill amount has to cancel out.  In that example Serg, the Code and the Date has to match.  So based on your example with the $-250, more and likely the date and code would differ from both of them.

Answer (score 0):

**This solution will give you the result without a self-join, and a single pass over the table.**

- We calculate the total number of positive numbers per `Serial` per absolute value of `BillAmt` (ignoring the negative sign)
- Same for the number of negatives
- We calculate a row number over the same grouping, per sign
- We filter only where the `BillAmt` is positive and current row number < = number of positives minus negatives, *or* it's negative and number of current row number <= negatives - positives

```sql
SELECT a.Serial, a.BillAmt, a.Date, a.Code 
FROM (
    SELECT a.*,
        positives = COUNT(CASE WHEN a.BillAmt > 0 THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY a.Serial, ABS(a.BillAmt)),
        negatives = COUNT(CASE WHEN a.BillAmt < 0 THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY a.Serial, ABS(a.BillAmt)),
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.Serial, ABS(a.BillAmt), SIGN(a.BillAmt) ORDER BY a.Date)
    FROM TableA a
) a
WHERE a.BillAmt > 0 AND rn <= positives - negatives
   OR a.BillAmt < 0 AND rn <= negatives - positives
ORDER BY a.Serial ASC;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e255c94b67e62d590e8a47a7d3f4572b)

Comment: Yes, this appears to be working.  Thank you.  Trying to understand this query, why use the SIGN function in the PARTITION parameter?

Comment: Because you want to number the rows per sign, so that you can limit it to the correct number of rows per sign in the `WHERE`. If you follow the logic you will see how that works